# Show job count in bash prompt only if nonzero

Tags: linux, bash, shell

A typical prompt in bash in something like:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w\$ "
```

The you can show the number of background jobs using `\j`, e.g.:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\w [\j]\$ "
```

Which is useful, because every now and then I forget I have a stopped job and only notice when it complains if I manually logout from the shell.

However, 95% of the time, the background job count is 0 and showing it in the prompt is superfluous.

How can I show the job count in the prompt, but only if it's nonzero?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can e.g. do something like this:

```
PS1='\u@\h:\w $([ \j -gt 0 ] && echo [\j])\$ '
```

Comment: Note that this shows stopped **and running** jobs (although the distinction might not matter to you)

Comment: Excellent example, including the single quoting and subshell.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not work for me (I have got Bash v4.2.46). It throws an error like this:

```
[: \j: integer expression expected
```

I had to use PROMPT_COMMAND to achieve the same functionality:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND=__prompt_command
function __prompt_command() {
    local JOBS=$(jobs | wc -l | tr -d 0)
    PS1="\u@\h:\w [${JOBS}]\$ "
}
```

Comment: It might be because the `$()` command substitution syntax was introduced in Bash 4.3. Try ```PS1='\u@\h:\w `[ \j -gt 0 ] && echo [\j]`\$ '``` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea I am not Bash expert, but I doubt it. Even in "GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release" this syntax works. I haven't seen in any Bash tutorial some warning about the $(...) syntax.

Comment: I think this comes from using `PS1="..."` instead of `PS1='...'`. I got the same error before I changed it.